# Getting wrong PackageName from context and I cannot touch that code

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I was getting a different "PackageName" from:

`context.getPackageName()` --> (return the application id?)
instead of using `getClass().getPackage().toString()`

But I cannot change that part of the code.

So my workaround was to change the applicationId from build.gradle, and package in manifest.

Comment: not sure what the issue is. What are you trying to do

Comment: `context.getPackageName()` not the same as `getClass().getPackage()`, first is root package and second is `class` package

Answer (score 2):

The context.getPackageName() method is used to identify the application using the application id, like com.whatsapp or com.facebook.orca it may be used during interprocess communication.

If you want to identify the package that your class is located you should use getClass().getPackage().toString().

Notice that the application id may not be the same as the package name of your class.

I also recommend that you DON'T change the application id on the manifest if the app is already on the Playstore, since it is an unique indentifier and it will probably don't let you update the app with a different id